# Vicious Crusade - is it against vice or is it bad itself?

Tags: meaning

There's a music band named Vicious Crusade.
How would you understand that naming, is it a crusade against vice and vicious people or is that crusade itself vicious?

Comment: [Inquisition](https://www.google.com/search?q=inqustion&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8#q=inquisition+band) was already taken.

Comment: Does a *vicious dog* subscribe to an ethical framework where he only bites vicious people? If you want to express the notion of a crusade against vice, you should [just say that](http://cdnc.ucr.edu/cgi-bin/cdnc?a=d&d=SFC19001012.2.25).

Comment: I believe it's not that simple. A crusade is an action, unlike the dog. And there are cases when it's used to mean "against" and even "for".
A great thanks for the link, however!

Comment: Can you provide an example of where an adjective modifying *crusade* identifies the *target* of the crusade? I can envision situations where the juxtaposition of two *nouns* can capture the idea of a targeted crusade (*drug crusade*) but not one where an adjective modifies "crusade". Which is why, I think, the author of the article I linked to, and many others like it which turn up when you google `[crusade against vice]`, were forced to say *exactly that*, and not "vicious crusade" (and neither is it possible to imagine that phrase describing a crusade against "viciousness").

Comment: More problematical is, perhaps, the use of the word *crusade*. Itself. President George W Bush dropped a fearful clanger when he talked about a *crusade against terrorism*, forgetting the origin of the word, and its resonances in the Islamic world, nearly one millennium after the events in question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*... is that crusade itself vicious?*

**Only** that.

No dictionary allows /the other/your/ meanings in such a context. You have to read more fiction, as no experienced reader would go to that interpretation.